# how to exclude a rule in laravel validation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I am building a user's resignation inside the dashboard with Form Request Validation. it works well in store resource, but I need to exclude the password role in updating resource, so if the user leaves it empty I will store the old password

my validation file

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'avatar' => ['image', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:700'],
            'second_name' => ['required', 'max:60'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 'max:255'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case just use `'sometimes'` for updating password and not `'required'`.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'avatar' => ['image', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:700'],
            'second_name' => ['required', 'max:60'],
            'password' => ['sometimes', 'confirmed', 'max:255'],
```

Validating when present see docs here: [sometimes rule laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present)